# CSS - Transition for 'Overflow'?

Tags: html, css

I got a `footer` with some scrollable content with `overflow-y`.
Everything else on the page is very smoothly animated with CSS transitions, but as the scrollbar appears in the footer just when hovering, it looks really stupid when it doesn't have any transition. Take a look ***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/TFUmg/)***. 
Is there a way to make a smooth transition for it?

**CSS:**

```
footer
{
    background-color:#333333;
    position:fixed;
    height:4%;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: right;
    transition: all ease 1.1s;
    color: white;
    background-image:url('world1.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom ;
    background-size: contain;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

footer:hover {
height: 400px;
opacity: 0.95;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: How should that look like??? You could use a div covering an always present scrollbar (overflow-y: scroll), which you can fade out and fadeIn.

Comment: It should look like how it is, but the scrollbar should fade-in-out on hover.

Comment: Then you would have to do it like a said.

Comment: I'm confused... Example please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this and place a div to hide the scrollbar. Its hacky, but scrollbars are not really supposed to be animated.

http://jsfiddle.net/ttgB8/

```
footer, 
.cover-scroll{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    transition: all ease 1.1s;
    height:4%;
}

footer    {
    width:99%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

footer:hover {
  opacity: 0.95;
  height: 400px;
}

.cover-scroll{ 
    background: #fff;
    width: 40px;
    right: 0px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}

.cover-scroll:hover, 
footer:hover .cover-scroll{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 400px;
 }
```

As an alternative you could search for custom-scrollbar-plugins like iScroll and the like.