# CSS change overflow with delay

Tags: css

Hey I have a "spoiler" which should be animated and scrollable. The only problem is that the scrollbar should only be shown after the transition.

Example Code:

```css
#spoiler{
  font-size:50px; 
  max-height:0px; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  transition:3s;
}
input#SpoilerBox:checked ~ #spoiler{
  max-height:200px; 
  overflow:auto
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
   <title>Spoiler</title>
  </head>

     <body>
       <input type="checkbox" id="SpoilerBox"/><label for="SpoilerBox">Spoiler</label>

       <div id="spoiler">
         Text<br>
         to spoiler
        </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you going to have a set-height container to show the spoiler in?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), `overflow` is not Animatable. So you might need to go with a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913565/css-transition-for-overflow)

Comment: Yes that was my problem. I solve the problem with JavaScript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit tricky - I have added a wrapper element, and use css `@keyframes`. Also I changed the `max-height` to `100px`, for it fit the snipped area

```css
#spoiler{
  font-size:50px; 
  overflow:auto; 
  height:0; 
  transition: height 3s;
}
#spoiler-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
}
input#SpoilerBox:checked ~ #spoiler {
  height: 100px;
}
input#SpoilerBox:checked ~ #spoiler #spoiler-wrapper{
  height:auto; 
  animation: grow 3s;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {height:0px;}
  to {height: 100px;}
}
@keyframes shrink {
  from {height:100px;}
  to {height: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="SpoilerBox"/>
<label for="SpoilerBox">Spoiler</label>
<div id="spoiler">
<div id="spoiler-wrapper">
   Text<br>to spoiler
</div>
</div>
```